# In a template, if a dependent name is a function, call it

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, type-traits

In my `TClass<T>::foo()` function, I'd like to invoke a `T` instance if and only if `T` is a function type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
struct TClass
{
    TClass(T value) : value(value) {}
    T value;
    void foo()
    {
        // if(value is std::function)
        //     call function;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TClass<int> t1{0};
    t1.foo();
    TClass<std::function<void()>> t2{[](){ std::cout << "Hello, World!\n"; }};
    t2.foo();
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: *"function type"* - `std::function` only? Function pointers? Lambdas? Function types (`void(int)`)? Class with overloaded `operator()`?

Comment: I don't know about that change @YSC. That's pretty substantial.

Comment: @Barry would you have answered the question in its original state?

Comment: Not directly relevant, but C++17 has [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) which you *may* find useful/interesting in this context.

Answer (score 7):

In C++11, the easiest way to do this is to re-deduce the value through a helper function:

```
template <typename U>
auto foo_helper(U const& f, int) -> decltype(f()) {
    return f();
}

template <typename U>
void foo_helper(U const&, long) {}

void foo() {
    foo_helper(value, 0);
}
```

The conversion from `0` to `int` is better than its conversion to `long`, so if the first overload is viable - it will be preferred. If the first overload isn't viable, then we call the second one.

---

If you really care *only* about `std::function`, then we can just have simpler overloads:

```
void foo_helper(std::function<void()> const& f) {
    f();
}

template <typename T>
void foo_helper(T const&) { }

void foo() {
    foo_helper(value);
}
```

Comment: No `enable_if`: nice!

Comment: The `decltype` and `enable_if` are effectively the same thing, @YSC.

Comment: @SergeyA explain that to library writers please. I'm sick of its verbosity.

Answer (score 4):

In C++17 you can do:

```
void foo() {
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<T>) {
        value();
    }
}
```

---

If you only wants to allow `std::function`, you'll need your own trait, e.g.:

```
template <class T>
struct is_stdfunction: std::false_type {};

template <class T>
struct is_stdfunction<std::function<T>: std::true_type {};

template <class T>
constexpr bool is_stdfunction_v = is_stdfunction<T>::value;

// Then in foo():
void foo() {
    if constexpr (is_stdfunction_v<std::decay_t<T>>) {
        value();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not [partial specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) ?

Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
struct TClass {
    TClass(T value) : value(value) {}
    T value;
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "T - other" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
struct TClass<std::function<T>> {
    TClass(std::function<T>  value) : value(value) {}
    std::function<T> value;
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "std::function" << std::endl;
    }
};
```